# What is the best way to configure winstonjs to use in a large expressjs application?

Tags: node.js, logging, express, winston

I've been trying to configure winston in my express.js app but I feel like all the examples I find are only focused on apps that have only one file (server.js)

I still didn't understand how to correctly configure it for user in multiple files (controllers,models,..).

I'm running into a ton of bugs trying out alternative ways of configuring (with a global variable and with a file where I config the logger that than is imported by the files where it is used where the closest I got, with express-winston I felt like it was just an error and Request logger and didn't understand how to log custom logs so I gave it up)

But it never works correctly!!
I'm not showing any code because I feel like I've gotten no where yet, and yes I have read tons of documentation..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach:

Project structure:

```
server.js
another.js
logger.js
```

app.js, another.js and any other script, where I need to log, I just require logger.js via Node's `require`

```
var logger = require("./logger");
logger.info("...");
```

and in logger.js, just setup you winstonjs logger. Bonus point: you can swap winston for any other logger with same API

logger.js

```
var winston = require("winston");

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({colorize: true, level: "info", prettyPrint: true}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: "log.log"})
    ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```